# How are updates to the style.css file in child theme recognized?

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

When I update the *style.css* in my active child theme, the changes are not immediately picked up.

I tried doing a `touch` on the file, but the results have been inconsistent.  It worked once, but did not work the next time.  The changes were recognized after waiting for some time (~15 minutes).  I checked the file timestamps and they

Is there something else that I need to do to let WordPress know that the style.css file has been updated for the current theme?  Is the browser's concept of time involved in the decision to include changes from the style.css file?

Note: I am using the `wp-enqueue-style()` approach instead of the `@import` method for including the parent style.css.

Update: I do refreshes on the browser side every time I update style.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the server-side cache system used by my service provider (SiteGround).  Their cPanel has a cache-flush device; using it solved the problem:

[image]

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462258/wordpress-child-theme-css-not-reflecting-on-site) also helped.

Here's a link to the SiteGround page describing the system: [SiteGround static cache](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/supercacher/static_cache.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you stylesheet is cached by your browser. This is no problem specific to WordPress, but will happen with every resource that you open in browser. The second thing that can (and probably will) be happening is that you have some sort of server side cache. You can work around your webservers caching, by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or the same with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> – as long as your server sends a proper `Cache-Control` header, else it won't work as your servers cache will refuse to react on commands from the outside world (your client/browser).

Aside from that, you can tell the server that you have a *new* resource every time you have a change to your stylesheet. This can simply be done by appending a query argument like `?<key>=<value>`. The easiest way to do so, is to append a UNIX timestamp of the last time your file was modified:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'child-style-css',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/style.css",
        false,
        filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory()."/style.css" )
    );
}
```

This will produce an HTML tag like the following, where the query argument appended is `ver` and the value is `1456786622`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" 
    href="https://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css?ver=1456786622">
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did not see your comment about server-side caching until after I added my own answer.  Also, I don't quite understand the second paragraph - how does query argument figure into the code you have provided? Possibly I just don't have the necessary PHP background.

Comment: @Sabuncu See update. For the rest, you might want to exhibit how your server actually adds the `Cache-Control` header so you don't have localized knowledge for a single hoster with a GUI.

Comment: Kaiser, thanks again.  The "false" in the `wp_enqueue_style()` call - what is the syntax for that?  It follows a literal string but there's no separating syntactical element.

Comment: @Sabuncu I copy/pasted that quickly from another answer and seems like the origin had no commas. One line is one argument – fixed. Btw, [developer WordPress resources](https://developer.wordpress.com/), which includes source code.

Comment: Whew! Thanks, I am already apprehensive about learning PHP, and I was really spooked by that syntax. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your browser is caching your css file. Try to reload with `ctrl+F5` or for mac `cmd+shift+r`.

Comment: Just a `F5` reload or a clear cache reload `ctrl+f5`? Are the changes visible in the css file if you go to it through you browser?

Comment: Per your suggestion I have tried `CTRL+F5` but it did not help.

Comment: Are the changes visible if you load the css file in your browser?

Comment: Just enter the url of your stylesheet in your browser. something like `http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css`

Comment: Didn't realize you could do that! Yes, the contents of the file are up-to-date when I look at it through the browser.  But on another tab (Chrome), the site is out of date.

Comment: Try to make a change -> refresh the stylesheet tab -> and refresh the website tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36382/discussion-between-jorin-van-vilsteren-and-sabuncu).

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestions led me to the solution.